# Выбивает ошибку в функции a_proxy33()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, bs4

Почему у меня ошибку выбивает a_proxy33() и как спарсить ссылки?Нужно именно на селениуме парсить!!

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
options.binary_location ='\\chrome.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, 
executable_path=r"\chromedriver90.exe")
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) 
 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36'}
 options.add_argument("--headless")





def sait2_req2():#list index out of range
    url = "http://free-proxy.cz/ru/"
    id = "proxy_list"
    parsed = driver.get(url)
    table_id = parsed.find_element(By.ID, 'proxy_list')
    tbody = table_id.find_element_by_tag_name('tbody')
    rows = tbody.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")  # get all of the rows in the table
    for row in rows:
        # Get the columns (all the column 2)
        col = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[0]# note: index start from 0, 1 is col 2
        for rows in rows:
            col1 = rows.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[1]
            tre = col.text + ':' + col1.text
            print(tre)  # prints text from the element


sait2_req2()
def a_proxy33():#'NoneType' object has no attribute 'content'
    teg = "paginator"
    urt = "http://free-proxy.cz/"
    r = requests.get("http://free-proxy.cz/ru/")
    html = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')
    # get all of the rows in the table
    for el in html.select('.paginator'):
        url_more = el.select('a').get('href')
        print(url_more)
        #sait2_req2()                                  
   a_proxy33()#'NoneType' object has no attribute 'content'
```

> ##list index out of range ##

```
67.207.83.225:80
67.207.83.225:3128
67.207.83.225:80
67.207.83.225:8080
list index out of range
```

Проблема только в кусочке кода другие функции нормально выводятца.
А еще браузер открыт но почему-то через пять мин пишет ошибка.Почему-то не работает безголовый режим в хроме 90?П.с подправила но выдает такую ошибку ?
Почему-то ошибки именно в функции a_proxy33() возникают.

Comment: Добрый день. Было бы гораздо проще Вам помоч, если бы вы представили весь относящийся к вопросу код и сщбственно вывод самого исключения, которое Вы получаете

Comment: Неясно, где в коде эта ошибка случается. Нужен полный стектрейс, а не только сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: Уже сама исправила ту ошибку только вместо той ошибки теперь эта .Как исправить range()вставляла уже.Ошибку вот эту "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_element'"

Answer (score -1):

путь правильно указал? если правильно то дальше ты должен сравнить драйвер браузера который скачал и свой браузер по умолчанию. их версии должны совпадать. если они отличаются удали и скачай драйвер заново, совпадающий с браузером

Comment: Вообще бесполезный комент .Сорри но версия 90 у меня браузера и в первую очередь подключаю разными способами.Тему подправила.